# Showing that Tensor Product of Field Extensions is a Field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, tensor-products

Letting $A$ and $B$ be non-isomorphic degree 2 extensions of a field $F$, how can I show that $A\otimes_{F}B$ is a field?

Comment: Do you also want to include the case of fields of characteristic $2$?

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes, for an arbitrary field $F$.